# Are there any keyboard shortcuts to switch between tabs in terminal? 

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard

Are there any keyboard shortcuts to switch between tabs in terminal?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Default shortcuts**

These are the shortcuts listed under the `Terminal -> Window` menu. On older MacOS versions they were called *Select Next Tab* and *Select Previous Tab*.

- Show Next Tab: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> (selects the tab to the right of your current tab)
- Show Previous Tab: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd>  (selects the tab to the left of your current tab)

I think it would make more sense to say <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> / <kbd>[</kbd>, since that's actually what you type.

**How to set custom Terminal shortcuts?**

Since there are menu items that these shortcuts trigger, you can use `System Preferences-> Keyboard-> Keyboard Shortcuts-> App Shortcuts` to reassign the shortcuts to whatever you want.
Click `+` to add a shortcut:

1. `Application` field - select `Other...` (at the bottom) and navigate to `Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal.app`.
2. `Menu Title` field - type the name of your shortcut, e.g. *Show Next Tab* (you can find the exact shortcut name in the `Terminal -> Window` menu, where the default shortcuts are listed)
3. `Keyboard Shortcut` field - press your custom shortcut keys.
   [image: Adding custom shortcut on old MacOS (prior to 10.11). Details might differ on new OSes.]

Comment: On a German keyboard the combos are: CMD+Ä and CMD+Ö (yes, with the 'Umlaute') :)

Comment: I'm curious, are those located just above and to the left of the right shift key?

Comment: Diagonal to the top left. So I guess it's the same location!

Comment: Defaults seem so foreign (but I'm not a heavy mac user...), Chrome and my text editor use Meta + Alt + Arrows to flip through tabs, but Terminal.app is a special snowflake I guess.

Comment: From the screenshot, to modify the Terminal app, the Application should be Terminal.app (under Applications > Utilities).

Comment: As of OS X El Capitan, the Menu Title is now **`Show`** Next Tab.

Comment: If you have attached an external keyboard the shortcut can not be registered.

Answer (score 30):

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + arrow keys is also a valid option.

Enjoy!

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down. Works for me.

Comment: no source, no reference, bit short on explaining ect..

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Mavericks.

Comment: Works great for me on Yosemite. This is a far better answer for people with non-english keyboards where the braces are hard to type.

Comment: Works for me on Yosemite as well. You can use Command + arrows to switch terminal windows and add shift to switch tabs inside the window.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to choose your own shortcut for switching tabs in terminal:

`open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Keyboard.prefPane/`

Application Shortcuts > (Add) > Application (Other...) > Applications/Utilities/Terminal

Menu titles:

```
Select Next Tab
Select Previous Tab
```

I've chosen, for example, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>⇦</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>⇨</kbd>.

Comment: Is `Select Next Tab` a reserved command on Mac?  I mean, I don't get how the OS will understand this.

Comment: Yea, this is what I would like to set my Terminal shortcut to be too since every other application with tabs uses this. But it doesn't work when I add it in shortcuts.... How does mac know what command to do?

Comment: If a new OS X version has changed the `Terminal` app menu item titles, then change it accordingly.